# Can't connect to Azure Notification Hub

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azureservicebus, azure-notificationhub

I can't connect to Microsoft Azure Notification Hub to manage the subscriptions (get registrations and send notifications). I have a simple C# console tool and executing NotificationHubClient methods' the exception appears: (401) Not Allowed..TrackingId:****uid_here*****

With Fiddler, I got the following raw error message:
***HTTP/1.1 401 40103: Invalid authorization token signature***

I'm using the Assembly Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs v2.16.0.0 with the correct connection string (full share access) and WindowsAzure.ServiceBus v4.0.0. I copied the exact connection string from the azure manage portal and I also tried to connect with the ServiceBusExplorer, but it was not possible and the with this tool I have the error:

*`Receivera:InternalServiceFault`The server was unable to process the request due to an internal error.  For more information about the error, either turn on IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults (either from ServiceBehaviorAttribute or from the <serviceDebug> configuration behavior) on the server in order to send the exception information back to the client, or turn on tracing as per the Microsoft .NET Framework SDK documentation and inspect the server trace logs.*

Anyone having this kind of trouble?

Tks!

**UPDATED:
Thank you guys. It was a connection string problem. The mistake was the SharedAccessKeyName. The current default name is DefaultFullSharedAccessSignature and my initial key RootManageSharedAccessKey doesn't work anymore. I think It could be changed by azure. It is not accepting connections with the root key... Or it was changed by someone else for other reason.**

Comment: can you share the connection string, without the secret itself?

Comment: Yes, sure. The notification hub connection string is the exact I copied from Azure connection information:
Endpoint=sb://myservice.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=DefaultFullSharedAccessSignature;SharedAccessKey=TheSecretKeyHere

Comment: where do you specify the hub name? posted an answer.

Comment: we also had this issue where an old notification hub was still logging in with `RootManageSharedAccessKey`  and this was causing issues.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to your description, I built my console application, installed [Microsoft Azure Notification Hubs 1.0.7](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs/) and got connection string from the azure manage portal to test this issue. It could work as expected on my side, here is the code snippet, you could refer to it:

```html
NotificationHubClient hub = NotificationHubClient.CreateClientFromConnectionString("{connection-string-with-full-access}", "{your-notification-hub-name}");
await hub.SendWindowsNativeNotificationAsync("{your-Windows-native-payload}");
```

For more details, you could follow this official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-windows-mobile-push-notifications-mpns#send-push-notifications-from-your-backend) about sending push notifications from your back-end.

Comment: Thank you! It is correct. I updated my question with the answer.

Comment: If my effort could help you to locate the cause, you could kindly make as an answer. Or you could post your reply and mark your reply as an answer instead of updating your original question for a better way to help other community members who could encounter this similar issue.

Answer (score 2):

Your service bus connection string must include the Notification Hub name:

> Endpoint=sb://my-notification-bus.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=DefaultFullSharedAccessSignature;SharedAccessKey=MySharedAccess;**EntityPath=my-hub-name**

Comment: Thank you. Now its working. But the mistake was the SharedAccessKeyName name's. I don't understand what happened. In the beginning the SharedAccessKeyName was called "RootManageSharedAccessKey". Now the name is DefaultFullSharedAccessSignature. I have this infrastructure working for at least 2 years. Maybe azure changed it, or someone else changed it and didn't tell me.

Comment: @rd_rscan we had the same issue.